# How to take the square root of quad_form output in CVXPY?

Tags: python, square-root, cvxpy

I am trying to solve a problem that involves `\sqrt{w^t \Sigma w}` in the objective function. To compute `w^t \Sigma w`, I use the [`quad_form`](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/blob/master/cvxpy/atoms/quad_form.py#L204) function. How do I take its square root?

When in the code I try to write

```
risk = sqrt(quad_form(w, E))
```

I am getting a DCP rule error but I am pretty sure it is convex given the other constraints I have. So the question is not really about maths but the actual implementation of the convex program.

The problem I am trying to solve is

```
ret = mu.T*w 
risk = sqrt(quad_form(w, E))
gamma.value = distr.pdf(distr.ppf(alpha)) / (1 - alpha)
minimizer = Minimize(-ret + risk * gamma) #cvxpy.sqrt(risk) * gamma) 
constraints = [w >= 0, 
               b.T * log(w) >= k] 
prob = Problem(minimizer, constraints)
prob.solve(solver='ECOS_BB',verbose=True)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly related to programming but mathematical way of thinking.

Comment: Yes, the question as it stands is a bit vague. I have added some more clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to take the square root of the quadratic form, matrix `Sigma` must be positive semidefinite. Compute a [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) `Sigma = Q.T * Q` and then include the term `norm(Q*w,2)` in your objective function.

Comment: Thanks. My question was a bit vague. I have added some more details.

Comment: I got the same error message when I tried to compose `sqrt` and `quad_form`. I would just use the Cholesky decomposition.

Comment: Unless I am missing something $w^t Q w$ is not the same as $\sqrt(w^t \Sigma w)$. The latter is not even convex outside of a certain region - I believe that is where I am getting the issue.

Comment: Note that `norm(Q*w,2)` is just the 2-norm, not the 2-norm **squared**!

Comment: Got you. Thanks!