# CVXPY Square root of Singular Quadratic

Tags: python, square-root, cvxpy

I need to model sqrt(x^T C x) for a singular positive semidefinite matrix C. Here, it is proposed to use norm(Q*x) where Q is obtained from the Cholesky decomposition of C.

[How to take the square root of quad_form output in CVXPY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539925/how-to-take-the-square-root-of-quad-form-output-in-cvxpy)

But, np./scipy.linalg.cholskey does not work for singular matrices.

PS, using SVD or eigenvalue decomposition is too slow for my application.

PS2, this post [Numpy Cholesky decomposition LinAlgError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604498/numpy-cholesky-decomposition-linalgerror) does not help as it does not offer a solution. Also, the matrix in the question seems to have negative eigenvalues (rather than being singular).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy Cholesky decomposition LinAlgError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604498/numpy-cholesky-decomposition-linalgerror)

Comment: That post does not suggest a solution.

Comment: To clarify, `C` denotes the covariance matrix?

Comment: That's right. A singular one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using the ldl decomposition

```
    L,d,_ = scipy.linalg.ldl(C)
    d = np.diag(d).copy()
    inds = d >= d.max()*1e-8

    d = d[inds]
    d = np.sqrt(d)
    d.shape = (-1,1)
    Q = d * L.T[inds]


    loss = cp.norm(cp.matmul(Q, x))
```

The ldl decomposition needs scipy >= 1.1 though.